# Selecting from two different tables and order by for one and limit results of the other?

Tags: mysql, select

Please someone help.

I have two tables, car_table and add_table, they are completely different tables.

car_table:

```
+---------+-------------+------+-----+------------------+----------------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default          | Extra          |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+------------------+----------------+
| id      | int(3)      | NO   | PRI | NULL             | auto_increment |
| car     | varchar(15) | NO   |     | NULL             |                |
| manuf   | varchar(10) | NO   |     | NULL             |                |
|timestamp| timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP|                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+---------------------------+
```

Sample Data:

```
+----+--------+-------+-----------+
| id | car    | manuf | timestamp | 
+----+--------+-------+-----------+
|  1 | M5     | BMW   | time      |
|  2 | Golf   | VW    | time      | 
|  3 | Toyota |pickup | time      |
|  4 | Ford   | focus | time      |
+----+--------+-------+-----------+
```

add_table

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
|add_id | int(3)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| link  | varchar(15) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| s_img | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Sample Data:

```
+-------+--------+-------+
|add_id | link   | s_img |
+-------+--------+-------+
|  1    | link   | img   |
|  2    | link   | img   | 
|  3    | link   | img   | 
|  4    | link   | img   | 
+-------+--------+-------+
```

I am trying to write a select statement that will order the car_table by timestamp and limit the add_table to 3 results, mixing the results so that a add_table results are separated by car_table results.

Below is what I have so far but not sure where to go from here. (update: this seems to partially work, however not sure what it is ordering the add_table by and not sure if it's even the correct way of doing it.)

```
SELECT  id,car,manuf,timestamp,
FROM car_table
UNION ALL
SELECT add_id,link,s_img,NULL AS timestamp
FROM add_table ORDER BY TimeStamp
```

Comment: In the absence of sample data, I don't see how `car_table` and `add_table` are related.  Also, the query you gave above uses two _different_ tables.  What is going on here?

Comment: the question has been updated

Comment: the tables aren't related at all, that's why i'm asking the question.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Hopefully, to display 3 results from `car_table` and then one from `add_table` then another 3 from  `car_table` then one from `add_table` and so on and so on.